# Refresh visualforce page after save button

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, controller, refresh

I created a visualforce page with some input fields and a save button and there is also an output field which is based on the input fields.

After I click save, the output field remains the same and I need to refresh the page to see the changes.

I want the visualforce to refresh itself but it won't.
I tried `oncomplete="location.reload()"` or `return ApexPages.currentPage` (in the controller) and similar things but nothing seems to work.

Any help ?
Thanks.

Comment: is your VF page inline VF page?

Comment: do not use `rerender` attribute.

Comment: The VF is inside the opportunity layout

Comment: If return null; does not work, please share save button code on Visualforce page and controller's method.

Comment: @TusharSharma, why ReRender should not be used here?

Comment: @osos9, do you want to refresh just this piece of page, which is represented as VF page or the whole page in browser?

Comment: Doesn't matter which way, but I will try the rerender attribute tomorrow morning, Thanks

Comment: osos9 solved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
return null;
```

in save method of VF's controller?

EDIT:

add `ReRender="myForm"` to your actionButton

Comment: 'return null' is already in but it doesn't do much

Comment: @osos9, what does id do?

Comment: It doesn't refresh the page

Comment: Wow. Yes, it shouldn't, Please, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12804530/apexcommandbutton-cant-return-nothing . Have you tried return ApexPages.currentPage();

Comment: Yes, I mentioned it in the question

Comment: @osos9, if it is so, then you don't call your save method from VF page. You need to have <apex:commandButton action="{!mySave}" value="Save"/>

Comment: If I didn't have that, I couldn't save anything  but I could. It just won't refresh the page

Comment: Try add ReRender="myForm" to your actionButton

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/40037)

Comment: @mast0r, I know, that this doesn't answer the question. I don't critique the author, I'm asking clarification questions.